# Need to right to left align using DITA-OT for arabic language

Tags: pdf, xslt, dita, oxygenxml, dita-ot

I'm converting DITA to PDF using DITA-OT 1.8.5 for the arabic input file.

After I got convert I'm getting the left to right align view for the PDF output.

[image: The indent is starting from the left]

[image: The order list also need to come from right to left with numbers]

I need the right to left alignment with the right indent,

Please suggest me the coding from the **org.dita.pdf2** plugin of DITA-OT. Where i need to change for getting the mirror reflex for the output. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the root element of the document have the @xml:lang attribute set to ar-sa? If not, try that first. Otherwise you'll have to set up an override to set the text-align attribute for all the blocks. However, I suspect that you do not have the @xml:lang attribute set correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Its working fine @julioV. Can you please tell me the ar-sa xml file. where i have to find. because in the dita-ot i18n folder its not available.